# having trouble displaying associated stored images from paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm able to upload multiple images using paperclip through a nested form, and I can view the json, the database records, and I can see the images that are stored in my folders, but its not displaying it in `view.html.erb`

```
<%= @project.project_images.to_json %>
```

So this displays all my records for @project.

Now I'm trying this:

```
<% @project.project_images do |pic| %> 
  <%= pic %>
  <%= image_tag pic.url(:thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

Nothing happens.

I have this in my controller:

```
has_attached_file :photo, 
                 :styles => { :large => "800x800>", :medium => "500x500>", :thumb => "150x150#" }, 
                 :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this

```
<%= image_tag pic.url(:thumb) %>
```

should be this

```
<%= image_tag pic.photo.url(:thumb) %>
```

also please change this

```
<% @project.project_images do |pic| %>
```

to this

```
<% @project.project_images.each do |pic| %>
```

Comment: one more change im going to add to the answer. might be that is  the reason

Comment: Ahhhh, duh! i'm a 'tard... forgot the `.each`!